# Creating Incidents in Dynatrace for method invocation measures

Tags: dynatrace

I have created 2 method invocation measures in Dynatrace for 2 method calls in the backend.

I want to create an Incident in Dynatrace if method 1 is called less than 80% of the times method 2 is called.

Is there a way to do this in Dynatrace?

When I open the dialog in Dynatrace to create an incident, I see we can add multiple measures in the condition. But I couldn't find a way to set the threshold for method invocation measure 1 to be 80% of the total number of calls for method invocation measure for a given timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "rate measure" can do what you are looking for. I.e. with this you define one base measure and a fraction measure. The counts of these two compared to each other are the rate computed by that new measure.

See e.g. https://answers.dynatrace.com/storage/attachments/4622-capture.jpg and https://answers.dynatrace.com/spaces/148/uem-open-q-a_2/questions/186446/how-to-setup-a-rate-measure-correctly.html for sample configurations.